# Area between curve and two lines

Tags: definite-integrals

I have three functions: 
$$y=5+\sin x\\ y=-x+0.5\\ y=2x+1$$I have to calculate area between them. I made:  $-x+0.5=2x+1$ and I got $x=-\frac16$. What shall I do next to get the area?

Comment: Yes, the two lines intersect at $x= -\frac{1}{6}$.  For x< -1/6 you want to integrate $5+ sin(x)- (0.5- x)$.  For x> -1/6 you want to integrate $5+ sin(x)- (2x+ 1)$.  The hard part is finding the lower and upper bounds on the integral.  The lower bound is x satisfying $5+ sin(x)= 0.5- x$ and the upper bound is x satisfying $5+ sin(x)= 2x+ 1$.  You will need to use some numerical method to determine those values.

Answer (score 0):

You won't find nice solutions to $2x+1 = 5 \sin x$ or $-x+0.5 = 5+\sin x.$ You can get numerical answers, however.  The first has solution $x = 2.35.$  The second has solution $x=-5.32.$ You'll have to break the area into two integrals:

$$\int_{-5.32}^{-1/6} (5+\sin x) -(-x+0.5) \; dx + \int_{-1/6}^{2.35} (5+\sin x) -(2x+1) \; dx.$$

Comment: If I put -5.32 into sinx, is the -5.32 in radians?

Comment: In calculus we always use radians.  Otherwise the derivative of $\sin x$ is not $\cos x.$